# Access nested dictionary swift 3

Tags: swift

I make POST request and I get this response

```
{
  "id": "6QRqYlqpv",
  "hostname": "twitter.com",
  "link": "https://twitter.com/AliNatham/status/869551271409328129",
  "title": "869551271409328129",
  "filename": "869551271409328129.mp4",
  "originalFormat": "mp4",
  "originalType": "video",
  "formats": [
    {
      "format": "mp4",
      "type": "video",
      "url": "https://loadercdn.io/download?id=6QRqYlqpv&format=mp4",
      "directUrl": "https://loadercdn.io/download?id=6QRqYlqpv&direct=true&format=mp4",
      "directUrl_": "directUrl will be deprecated soon, do not use",
      "filename": "869551271409328129.mp4"
    },
    {
      "format": "avi",
      "type": "video",
      "url": "https://loadercdn.io/download?id=6QRqYlqpv&format=avi",
      "directUrl": "https://loadercdn.io/download?id=6QRqYlqpv&direct=true&format=avi",
      "directUrl_": "directUrl will be deprecated soon, do not use",
      "filename": "869551271409328129.avi"
    }]
}
```

I tried to access "format": "mp4" like this
print(json["formats"]?["url"] as Any)
but I get nil

Comment: What are you using to parse the json to swift?

Comment: guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

Answer (score 0):

Your `formats` is an array. You need to access the nested object in the array first and access `url` on that.

Try `print(json["formats"][0]?["url"] as Any)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

```
let formats = json["formats"] as! Array<[String:AnyObject]>
print(test[0]["url"] as! String)
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. It assumes `formats` has at least 1 element and it assumes the value you want is the first format. That may not always be the case.